# Wso2 iot server - Samet time two policy

Tags: wso2, iot

wso2 iot 2 policies can not be assigned to a device on the server at the same time?

Why does not the other one work when a policy is defined?
https://wso2.org/jira/secure/attachment/40091/PolicyPriorityUI.png

Answer (score 0):

IoT server does not support adding multiple policies to the device at the same time. Only one policy can be assigned to the device at a given time.